# How to group rows together all having a common title in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Is it possible to group rows together where all the rows are actually outputted but in a very organized JSON format with one SQL query?

For example, if I have a table with columns: lastname, firstname, address, and phone number and I wanted to Group the rows together based on the first letters of their last name so that I have something.

{
{
letter: 'A',
rows: {
{
lastname: 'Anfar',
firstname: 'Peter',
address: 'Street city state country',
phone_number: 'phone number'
},

```
          {
            lastname: 'Akon',
            firstname: 'Clide',
            address: 'Street city state country',
            phone_number: 'user_phone_number'
          },
          {
            lastname: 'Abel',
            firstname: 'Nigel',
            address: 'Street city state country',
            phone_number: 'phone number'
          },
    }
},

{
   letter: 'B',
      rows: {
          {
            lastname: 'Best',
            firstname: 'Peter',
            address: 'Street city state country',
            phone_number: 'phone number'
          },

          {
            lastname: 'Bide',
            firstname: 'Clide',
            address: 'Street city state country',
            phone_number: 'user_phone_number'
          },
          {
            lastname: 'Biden',
            firstname: 'Nigel',
            address: 'Street city state country',
            phone_number: 'phone number'
          },
    }
}
```

}

I'm using laravel and I want to know if there's a way to achieve something like this

Comment: Not with SQL, no. But you could leverage the Laravel Collection class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `groupBy()`function of the collection.

Add a `letter` column to your query:

```
$q = User::query()
      ->selectRaw('LEFT(lastname,1) AS letter, lastname')
      ->get();
```

and then use `groupBy('letter')` to group the list

```
$q->groupBy('letter')
```